# Replace/Assign a value in select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

```
    select paymentType from paymentAccount


  output
  p
  f
```

How can i display the output like

```
  output
  Part
  Full
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite like:

```
select CASE paymentType WHEN 'p' THEN 'Part' WHEN 'f' THEN 'Full' END AS paymentType from paymentAccount
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE from paymentAccount

Comment: select CASE paymentType WHEN 'p' THEN 'Part' WHEN 'f' THEN 'Full' END AS Policy from paymentAccount.. this worked

Comment: @soul: Thanks a lot. I missed the sysntax. I stand corrected.